# how to provide custom variables in gitlab api?

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

based on the gitlab docs, one can trigger a job in the ci/cd pipeline and pass some parameters in the POST request as well. sample below. how to correctly read/parse the variables.json in gitlab ci/cd job ? say, i want to trigger test-job1 in my pipeline via following curl command, how to read the parameters passed in @variables.json in .gitlab-ci?

```
curl --request POST "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/project_id/trigger/pipeline" \
     --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
     --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" \
     --data @variables.json
```

.gitlab-ci.yml

```
build-job:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Hello, $GITLAB_USER_LOGIN!"

test-job1:
  stage: test
  script:
    - python3 mydumbscript.py $arg1 $arg2 $arg3

test-job2:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "This job tests something, but takes more time than test-job1."
    - echo "After the echo commands complete, it runs the sleep command for 20 seconds"
    - echo "which simulates a test that runs 20 seconds longer than test-job1"
    - sleep 20

deploy-prod:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "This job deploys something from the $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH branch."
  environment: production
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a sample `variables.json` file like this:

```json
{
  "job_variables_attributes": [
    {
      "key": "MY_VAR_1",
      "value": "foo"
    },
    {
      "key": "MY_VAR_2",
      "value": "bar"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then on the job that's going to be executed then you can do something like the following:

```
test-job1:
  stage: test
  script:
    - python3 mydumbscript.py $MY_VAR_1 $MY_VAR_2
```

The `--data @variables.json` is essentially exporting the defined variables in your JSON to be available within the job, so you can use them the same way you'd if those were defined at the `variables` keyword.

Comment: thank you. one minor doubt i have is, is it possible to trigger a particular job via gitlab api?

Comment: Happy to help! Yeah you can do that although it would be a totally separate question - you can use `rules` to control when your jobs run to achieve that level of control

Comment: thank you - here is my new question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78238090/how-to-run-particular-jobs-in-gitlab-ci-cd-via-gitlab-api

Comment: i posted a new question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78238090/how-to-run-particular-jobs-in-gitlab-ci-cd-via-gitlab-api