# How to run particular jobs in GitLab CI/CD via GitLab API?

Tags: python, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a curl command (see below), currently I have one job in my pipeline and when I execute the curl command below, it runs my pipeline and executes my only job, i.e `test-job1`. Now I have added `test-job2`. I will have more jobs in there, but I want to be able to configure the jobs such that I can pick and choose the jobs (create rule in the jobs essentially) such that I can run those particular jobs and only those jobs by curl command.

Can anyone provide me with all the steps?

```bash
curl --request POST "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/1412/pipeline" \
     --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
     --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" \
     --data @variables.json
```

```yaml
build-job:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Hello, $GITLAB_USER_LOGIN!"

test-job1:
  stage: test
  script:
    - python3 mydumbscript.py $arg1 $arg2 $arg3
how to run particular jobs in gitlab ci/cd via gitlab api? 
test-job2:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "This job tests something, but takes more time than test-job1."
    - echo "After the echo commands complete, it runs the sleep command for 20 seconds"
    - echo "which simulates a test that runs 20 seconds longer than test-job1"
    - sleep 20

deploy-prod:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "This job deploys something from the $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH branch."
  environment: production
```